# query_vars category_name only display one catgory out of multiple categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, query-variable

I am working on a plugin which alter the query arguments! Plugin uses `$wp_query->query_vars['category_name']` to get the category slugs. Everything works when I am fetching posts from one category. But when passing comma separated slugs `$wp_query->query_vars['category_name']` display only one first category.

This is the loop

```
$args = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'postcat,postcat2'
); 

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($custom_query);
```

And this is what I get when I print my query.

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => post
            [posts_per_page] => -1
            [category_name] => postcat,postcat2
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [post_type] => post
            [posts_per_page] => -1
            [category_name] => postcat
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] =>
```

I want to know why `$my_query->query_vars['category_name']` have only one category slug ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why downvote ? Please explain when you downvote a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `get_posts()` of `WP_Query` class, you will see this code block.

```
/*
 * Ensure that 'taxonomy', 'term', 'term_id', 'cat', and
 * 'category_name' vars are set for backward compatibility.
 */
if ( ! empty( $this->tax_query->queried_terms ) ) {

    /*
     * Set 'taxonomy', 'term', and 'term_id' to the
     * first taxonomy other than 'post_tag' or 'category'.
     */
    if ( ! isset( $q['taxonomy'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->tax_query->queried_terms as $queried_taxonomy => $queried_items ) {
            if ( empty( $queried_items['terms'][0] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            if ( ! in_array( $queried_taxonomy, array( 'category', 'post_tag' ) ) ) {
                $q['taxonomy'] = $queried_taxonomy;

                if ( 'slug' === $queried_items['field'] ) {
                    $q['term'] = $queried_items['terms'][0];
                } else {
                    $q['term_id'] = $queried_items['terms'][0];
                }

                // Take the first one we find.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // 'cat', 'category_name', 'tag_id'
    foreach ( $this->tax_query->queried_terms as $queried_taxonomy => $queried_items ) {
        if ( empty( $queried_items['terms'][0] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( 'category' === $queried_taxonomy ) {
            $the_cat = get_term_by( $queried_items['field'], $queried_items['terms'][0], 'category' );
            if ( $the_cat ) {
                $this->set( 'cat', $the_cat->term_id );
                $this->set( 'category_name', $the_cat->slug );
            }
            unset( $the_cat );
        }

        if ( 'post_tag' === $queried_taxonomy ) {
            $the_tag = get_term_by( $queried_items['field'], $queried_items['terms'][0], 'post_tag' );
            if ( $the_tag ) {
                $this->set( 'tag_id', $the_tag->term_id );
            }
            unset( $the_tag );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see inside the second `foreach` loop, for `category` taxonomy, WordPress only uses the first queried term to extract the slug from, then set it to the `query_vars`. The same happen to `post_tag`.

And why WordPress doing that, the comments have already said it all.